# How can I get the properties from a property Group of a Custom Control as an Object?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm working on a Custom Control that displays markers on Google Maps. I have a couple of properties like "maptype" , "zoom",  etc. It is easy to access them in Javascript: I can use `#{javascript:compositeData.zoom}` to get the value of the zoom property.

Now this is my problem: I use a group of properties for each marker. 
The name of the group is "marker" and a marker has 6 properties: "title", "layer", "infotext", "icon", "address" and "animation".

If I try to access the group with

```
var markers = #{javascript:compositeData.marker};
```

I'm getting an error in firebug:

> missing : after property id   var markers = [{layer=2,
>   address=Oldenzaal, animation=DROP, icon=/ogo_notes.png...

an arrow is pointing to the first = between layer and 2
(I am not allowed to put in an image in stackoverflow)

If I use

```
var markers = #{javascript:'"' + compositeData.marker + '"'};
```

markers is an Object, but each Object contains a string with all the propperties of the marker.

I know I can do some coding to make an object of each string, but this is not easy if not all propperties are required. If a propperty is not required than it will not show up in the string.

I guess that there must be a more easy way to get each marker as an object so I can get the value of the icon with code like:

```
var icon = marker.icon
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `compositeData.marker.icon` to get the property `icon` inside the group `marker`. If you have checked "Allow multiple instances" for the group then to get the properties you will have to go:

```
compositeData.marker[0].icon
compositeData.marker[1].icon
```

and so on...

**Update 26-Apr-2012 (Naveen)**

To use it with client side javascript you can try to put the value in a hidden input field like this:

```
<xp:inputHidden id="hdnIcon">
        <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:var value = new Array();
for (var i=0 ; i<compositeData.marker.length ; i++) {
    value.push(compositeData.marker[i].icon);
}
return @Implode(value, ",");}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
</xp:inputHidden>
```

The value of this hidden input field can be read through client-side javascript like this:

```
var value = document.getElementById("#{id:hdnIcon}").value.split(",");
for (var i=0 ; i<value.length ; i++) {
    <YOUR CODE>
}
```

Another way to do this can be to convert `compositeData.marker` and its contents to a JSON string and then run the client-side javascript on it.

Comment: Thank you Naveen, but how can I do now something like:

for (var i=0;i<#{javascript:compositeData.marker}.length;i++){
 var a = #{javascript:compositeData.marker[i].address};
 alert(a);
}

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that this is client side javascript I'm working in.


    var markers = #{javascript:compositeData.marker}; 

gives me the error as a have metioned, but I discoverd that


    var markers = '#{javascript:compositeData.marker}'; 

gives me back a string value with


    [{layer=2, address=Oldenzaal, animation=DROP, title=test title, icon=/logo_notes.png, infotext=fzxcxzv}, {layer=1, address=lonneker, animation=DROP, title=asdfasdfdafasfas, icon=/marker_pin_red.png, infotext=test}]

Comment: Can I use both client side javascript and serverside javascript and combine them?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a possible solution, as it was too big for comment.