# Creating a custom control group object?

Tags: xpages

I was having an issue with setting a property within a group within my custom control.

```
   compositeData.MyGroup.MyProperty = "foo";
```

I reported this to Notes tech support and they got back to me with a solution and I can't remember the details but the said I first need to create the group object.

Something like:

```
 compositeData.MyGroup = new GroupObject;
```

Of course that is not the right syntax.  Does anyone know how to create this object?

Comment: Can this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10300731/785061

Comment: I'm confused... you're trying to set the property from inside the custom control instead of passing it in from the containing XPage?

Comment: Mastering XPages page 355 talks about "Multiple Instances and Property Groups". Have a look at that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  To pass a property value back to the xPage using a group, you must do the following.

In the CC:

```
if (compositeData.MyGroup == null)
 compositeData.MyGroup = new com.ibm.xsp.binding.PropertyMap;

 compositeData.MyGroup.MyProperty = "Test";
```